# Container is unreachable from up services when using docker-compose run

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose config like the following:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  flask:
    command: [python, app.py]
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:5000:5000"
  frontend:
    command: [sh, -c, "npm run start"]
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:7600:7600"
    links:
      - flask
```

The `frontend` container has a webpack development server running which proxies `/api/*` path requests to `flask:5000` for processing. This works great when I use `docker-compose up -d`.

However, let's say I want to debug something in the flask app using `pdb`, and I run it manually instead using:

```
docker-compose stop flask 
docker-compose run --rm --service-ports flask python app.py
```

Then suddenly, my `frontend` service cannot proxy request to my `flask` service and I'm getting an error like: `Error occurred while trying to proxy request /testing from frontend:7600 to http://flask:5000 (ECONNREFUSED) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)`

What am I missing? How do I make this configuration work for interactive debugging of my python code?

Edit: I'm running `Docker version 18.09.0, build 4d60db4` and `docker-compose version 1.23.2, build 1110ad01`

Comment: what version of docker compose are you using?

Comment: @Siyu Added version info.

Comment: Links field is deprecated, do not use.
Why specifiying the ip in the ports field? Remove it and try again

Comment: @ChristianSauer It's a security good practice to use `127.0.0.1` when binding ports, that didn't cause any issues.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you run manually, the container name is no longer `flask`, you can see that with `docker network inspect your_network`.

You need to first `docker-compose rm flask` to free the name `flask`, then `docker-compose run --service-ports --name flask flask`.

Finally, I don't know how you use `pdb`, but you can normally use `docker-compose exec flask sh` or `docker attach container_id` to get an interactive prompt.